# order preserving function over Poset

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

I have a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) $G$ represents the dominance relation between solutions. A path from $x$ to $y$ means $y\succ x$ ($y$ dominates or better than $x$) where the absence of such a path means they are incomparable. The graph induces a Poset over the set of nodes (i.e. solutions). From my understanding this is called Hasse Diagrams (forgive my ignorance here).

I am trying to find a preserve ordering function over $G$ where if $x\succ y$ then $f(x)<f(y)$ and $f(x)=f(y)$ iff they are incomparable. Is such a function exists? One solution I am thinking about is to extract the set of chains for the Poset and then look for preserve ordering functions for total orders.

Answer (score 2):

In general this can not be accomplished. Consider the following poset: $\{a,b,c\}$, where $a<b$ but $a$ and $b$ are incomparable with $c$.

Suppose a function $f$ satisfies your requirements, then:
$$f(a) = f(c) = f(b),$$ which is a contradiction

Comment: Thanks. what about if I weaken the condition to only $x\succ y$ iff $f(x)<f(y)$ and omit the incomparability is it possible then? Also, what about if I have the set of chains of that Poset, is it possible to have an ordering preserve function?

Comment: Then it starts to depend on where your function $f$ is mapping to. The real numbers?

Comment: Yes I am mapping to integers/real numbers

Comment: Then it still wouldn't work since in the same counterexample $f(a)>f(b)$ so either $f(c)>f(b)$ or $f(a)>f(c)$ which are both contradictions.

Comment: In your example there is no edge connected to $c$ but I am sure there is no disconnected nodes in the DAG (i.e.all nodes are connected to some other nodes). Does this make any difference?

Comment: Doesn't really make a difference. Add for instance an element $d$ such that $d>c$ and $d>b>a$, then the counterexample would still work.

Comment: The real problem is that neither $\mathbb{R}$ nor $\mathbb{Z}$ have any incomparable elements.